# How can I send an email with a layout

Tags: grails, smtp

I am using grails mail plugin. When I submit my form, it will send an email from aaa@example.com to textField name="email successfully but how can I send an email with a layout...not blank like this picture http://www.4shared.com/photo/uT2YUCfo/Capture__2_.html or maybe some CSS..

**FORM**

```
<g:form action="send">
<table style="width:500px">
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>Your Email Address  </td>
       <td><g:textField style="width:250px" name = "email"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Your Name</td>
       <td><g:textField style="width:250px" name = "user"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="submit"/></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</g:form>
```

**MAIL CLOSURE**

```
def send = {
        sendMail {
            to params.email
            from "aaa@yahoo.com"
            subject "Test Reset Password"
            body(view:"/user/layoutmail",model:[name:params.user])
        }
        render "Email Terkirim"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't going to pick up a grails layout.  And you don't really want it to.  You should construct your email in a fashion that it could be a stand alone web page with no other dependencies.  All the static resources used should be accessible via a public URL.

Comment: hmmm..i cant understand..can you show me a little coding or what should i do with that coding..because its only layout in body of email..if i enter my email..so the server will send email to me with a layout in body..

Comment: I'm not sure how to make my answer more clear.  Do you know how to create a static HTML page?

Comment: Create the static HTML page, put it /user/layoutmail.gsp and your sendMail will send it.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding you when you say 'layout'.

Comment: yes,, please see this code : body(view:"/user/layoutmail",model:[name:params.user])... "layoutmail.gsp" when i sent to my email..it fill coding of layoutmail..example <html> <head> etc

Answer (score 1):

Well you could actually use a layout for emails, similarly how you would use layouts for view pages. What you would want to do is create a new layout and a view file for your email body content.

**Layout:  eg. ../views/layouts/emailLayout.gsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <style>
       a {color: #348eda;}
   </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
 </body>
</html>
```

**View eg. ../views/emails/welcomeEmail.gsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html" %>
<g:applyLayout name="emailLayout">
<html>
<body
   <a href="${welcome.url}">Your Welcome ${welcome.username}</a>
</body>
</html>
</g:applyLayout>
```

And to send the mail heres an example

```
def sendWelcomeMail(User user, String url){
    def rtn = [success:false]
    if(user) {
        def fooBar = [
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                url: url
        ]
        sendMail {
            async true
            to fooBar.email.trim()
            subject "Welcome Email"
            body(view: '/emails/welcomeEmail', model: [welcome: fooBar])
        }
        rtn.success = true
    }
    return rtn
}
```